# Serving same files in subdirectory as in root

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want my server to serve same files in subdirectories starting with character "v" as root of the website.

For example if someone visits [https://example.com/v[number]](https://example.com/v%5Bnumber%5D) they should see same content as in https://example.com.

How can i modify the .htaccess file to do so ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well. you need to implement an internal rewrite, nothing fancy here that I can spot:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?v\d+/(.+)$ /$1 [QSA,END]
```

I suggest you take a look into the documentation. As typical for OpenSource it is of excellent quality and comes with great examples:

- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/htaccess.html
- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html